# ¿Cómo se dice "remake" en castellano?

Tags: traducción, selección-de-palabras, artes-visuales

¿Existe alguna palabra en castellano -preferentemente aceptada por la RAE- que sea una traducción del concepto **remake**? Esto es, *hacer algo otra vez en el contexto de una película o libro*.

Me vienen a la cabeza las opciones:

- nueva versión (no es una sola palabra)
- reversionaje (¿?)

Pero no me acaban de convencer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Para estas cosas suelo tirar mucho de Fundéu, dado que son más ágiles reaccionando que la RAE (sin intención de queja, por supuesto).

[Su recomendación](http://www.fundeu.es/recomendacion/remake/) es que «**nueva versión**» o «**adaptación**» son más adecuados.

Respecto a «refrito», el [DRAE](http://dle.rae.es/refrito) es más claro en su 23ª edición que en la anterior: *Obra, especialmente literaria, rehecha, recompuesta o refundida a partir de otras.* Veo esta definición (y de hecho corrobora el uso que personalmente siempre había visto hasta el momento) bastante alejada del concepto habitual de *remake*.

Comment: +1 por adaptación. Totalmente apropiado.

Comment: Su buscas _remake_ en Wikipedia y cambias el idioma a Español, te sale _Adaptación_.

Comment: "Adaptación" no me parece tan apropiado. Para mí, "adaptar" implica trasponer de un medio o género a otro (de una novela a una película, de una película a un musical, etc). "Remake", en cambio,  es normalmente sólo una "nueva versión" de lo mismo.

Comment: @leonbloy también se puede adaptar dentro del mismo género sin que haya trasposición (por ejemplo, de película para adultos a película para niños; o de novela completa a lectura graduada), pero sí tienes razón en que quizás implicaría un resultado final que difiere del original en que se le han hecho algún tipo de ajustes.

Answer (score 4):

Se acostumbra decir **refrito** cuando hablamos de películas. También se puede usar *remake*, no tiene nada de malo. Y en cuanto a lo de una palabra, en español es bastante común que un concepto tenga varias palabras y no necesariamente una, así que **nueva versión** tampoco está mal.

Answer (score 4):

**Refrito** es usado sobre todo para obras dramáticas y escritas. <s>También se podría aplicar a las películas</s>, pero pienso que su uso es puramente ibérico o mexicano.

No pienso que en Latinoamérica la palabra sea reconocida con ese significado, es más probable que se tome el sentido literal, como papas fritas que son refritas o algo por el estilo.

Probablemente la reconozcan en Argentina, pero puedo decir que refrito no se dice en *Colombia, Ecuador, Venezuela, Panamá y Perú.*

Pienso que la palabra más segura para asegurar una comprensión más universal sería **rehacer**. `¡Rehicieron la película de Metrópolis!` por ejemplo. **Nueva versión** también es mejor.

Comment: "Rehacer" podría sonar como volver a hacer la película, sí, pero la misma como si se buscara una edición diferente de la misma y no un refrito precisamente.

Comment: @Jaime Un remake es literalmente rehacer la película. Es 100% apropiado. Un remake es rehacer la misma película. Refrito es lo siguiente: `especialmente refundición de una obra dramática o de otro escrito.` Por tanto es lo mismo que rehacer. La refundición = la "rerealización".

Comment: Abundando en la observación de @Joze♦, por «refrito» yo siempre había entendido justo lo que dice el DRAE en la 23ª edición: «Obra, especialmente literaria, rehecha, recompuesta o refundida a partir de otras». Es decir, para mí un refrito se parecería más (sin serlo) a un popurrí que a un *remake*.

Comment: @guillem sí esa interpretación me parece incluso mejor. Pienso me equivoqué respecto a refrito. Entonces al parecer refrito **no** es apropiado como equivalente de `remake`! Dado que remake es rehacer la película, no hacer un popurrí de obras.

Answer (score 4):

En el contexto de la música se usa bastante *reversión*.

En Argentina simplemente usamos *remake* para las películas, porque tenemos bastante la costumbre de usar palabras extranjeras para hablar, pero estimo que *reversión* podría ser una alternativa "más correcta".

El concepto de *refrito* definitivamente **no es común** acá - está más importado de centroamérica, creo. Si no fuera por Los Simpsons, creo que jamás habría escuchado "refrito".

Coloquialmente, si no es *remake*, lo más probable es que digamos *salió una nueva versión de Batman* o *rehicieron Batman* sin mucha aclaración más.

En cuanto a *adaptación*, entiendo que la usamos más para cuando se pasa de un formato a otro (por ejemplo, cuando hacen una película basada en un libro o en una obra de teatro) que para una nueva versión de la misma obra en el mismo medio.

Comment: Adhiero. Lamentablemente, "reversión" (palabra nueva, de construccción correcta, y que va ganando uso) colisiona con otra ya existente  (reversión: acción y efecto de revertir) http://lema.rae.es/drae/srv/search?id=wwM8zHPoCDXX2VPWzstG

Answer (score 4):

En Colombia se usa la palabra ***reencauche***.

El término surge del mundo del automovilismo, donde *reencauchar* es el proceso por el cual a una llanta (o neumático ó goma) usada se le vuelven a grabar los surcos.

Se habla de *reencauche* de canciones, novelas de televisión, series de televisión y películas.

Ejemplo:

> La película de 1998 "You've Got Mail" (conocida en español como "Tienes un e-mail") es un *reencauche* de la película de 1940 "The Shop Around the Corner".

Comment: Si señor, así decimos en Colombia. Bienvenido +1